# Calabash Android can run apk

Tags: android, calabash

I'm real new to Calabash and I can't understand what is wrong.

I installed everything and it seems to go smoothly. I'm using windows 7. I created the apk using IntelliJ and used the debug.keystore.

When I try to run the tests with the command "calabash-android run app.apk -v" this is what I get:

```
2014-02-12 17:05:09 - JDK found at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
2014-02-12 17:05:09 - Android SDK found at: C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514\sdk
No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreating test server.
2014-02-12 17:05:09 - "\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin/keytool.exe" -v -printcert -J"-Dfile.enco
ding=utf-8" -file "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/55654564654/META-INF/CERT.RSA"
2014-02-12 17:05:09 - MD5 fingerprint for signing cert (D:/Work/app/Dev/android/features/app.apk): 22:33:44:...............
2014-02-12 17:05:09 - D:/Work/app/Dev/android/features/app.apk was signed with a certificate with fingerprint 22:33:44:D8:..................
2014-02-12 17:05:09 - "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45/bin/keytool.exe" -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:/Users/user/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -J-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
2014-02-12 17:05:10 - Key store data:
2014-02-12 17:05:10 - Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: 21/05/2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 519aa32f
Valid from: Tue May 21 01:26:55 IDT 2013 until: Thu May 14 01:26:55 IDT 2043
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  22:33:44:...............
         SHA1: 22:33:44:D8:..................
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.20/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:25:in ``': No such file or directory - C:/Program Files/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514/sdk/build-tools/18.0.1/aapt dump badging "D:/Work/app/Dev/android/features/app.apk" (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.20/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:25:in `aapt_dump'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.20/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:9:in `package_name'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.20/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in calabash_build'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.20/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:37:in `chdir'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.20/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:37:in `block in calabash_build'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:83:in `mktmpdir'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.20/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:36:in `calabash_build'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.20/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:45:in `build_test_server_if_needed'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.20/bin/calabash-android-run.rb:16:in `calabash_run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.20/bin/calabash-android:71:in`<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/calabash-android:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/calabash-android:23:in `<main>'
```

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is with your path: `C:/Program Files/...` android is based in linux and has problems reaching paths with spaces, if you move your file it could work.

Comment: Which file do you think I should move? I'm trying to run the test in the same location of the apk

Comment: take a look at this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-android/_t6LtjJlFKw  it may help you

Comment: I've seen this, they have different errors. I also tried to run "calabash-android resign app.apk" like suggested, still not working :(

Comment: can you open your android sdk manager and check if you have installed Android 4.3 (API 18) ?

Comment: I did - I installed also 19 and all the android build-tools from the sdk manager. Also the path to aapt.exe exists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47335/discussion-between-benny-and-dyna)

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in ANDROID_HOME path — it's a problem. Try to:

1. Move Android SDK from `C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514` to a path without spaces, e.g. `C:adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514`;
2. Change `ANDROID_HOME` environment to a new path.